# Vue: Using input value in function

Tags: vue.js

I am using Single File Components and I have a modal component that has an 
input box but I can't get the value of the input in a function below using the v-modal name.  It keeps coming back as 'name is not defined'.  Am I using the v-model attribute incorrectly?

```
<template>
<input v-model="name" class="name"></input>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        methods: {

           applyName() {
                let nameData = {{name}} 
           }
        }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you're using the v-model property incorrectly.

First off you need to define a piece of state in your component, using data:

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    name: '',
  }),
  methods: { 
    log() {
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }
}
```

You can then bind this piece of data in your component using `v-model="name"`, just like you did. However, if you want to access this piece of state in your method, you should be using `this.name` in your `applyName()` method.

Your `{{name}}` syntax is used to get access to the data in your template, like so:

```
<template>
  <span>
    My name is: {{name}}!
  </span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this` pointer to access the model:

```
<template>
    <input v-model="inputName" class="name"></input>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                inputName: '',
            }
        },

        methods: {

            applyName() {
                // Notice the use of this pointer
                let nameData = { name: this.inputName }; 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i guess it will help if he referenced `let ref = this;` so that when the method gets deeper he has a reference for the model

Answer (score 0):

Look at the doc https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components

In the template, you are referring by name to data, computed or methods.  In this case, it refers to data. When the input changes the name then the data is updated.

It is possible to use in a function referring to this.

```
<template>
<input v-model="name" class="name"></input>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
           return { name: '' }
        },
        methods: {

           applyName() {
                let nameData = this.name 
           }
        }
     }
</script>
```